# Better mode in export datapump

Tags: oracle, schema, migration, import, export

I'm a complete newbie in oracle databases. I'm just curious on what mode is better when you want to migrate your database to another host by using data pumping. Lately, I'm having a problem on import datapump. I used export in schema mode and it seems that some of my packages were not stored correctly or somehow invalid. But when I checked my database if it has some invalid packages(not compiled after impdp) it appears that the packages were missing. I found out that I had an error about "Tablespace $tablespacename does not exist". I really don't have any idea where that tablespace came from because when I checked out my old database, it seems that $tablespacename does not exist. I looked over all the users but I really can't find that $tablespacename. Now I am too confused about where did I got that $tablespacename.

Comment: Check the view dba_tablespaces, it will be there.

Comment: As well as the above, you might need to use the `impdp` `remap_tablespace` option

Comment: Please provide the complete error message and the database version that you are using. Tablespace is a logical entity which holds the objects owned by a schema. During export it only exports the DDL of the objects and rows. So before import there should have the tablespace to hold the objects that are about to be imported or you can remap the tablespace if you want to use different tablespace name as Phil mentioned earlier.